# Vimeo API help using oauth2 and node/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth, vimeo

I'm trying to create a simple search vimeo search query inside of my node/express application, but I'm completely lost on authenticating the api with oauth2. I've installed vimeo via npm but I'm just staring at [the github](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js) with no understanding of how to implement this. Do I need to create a specific directory to authenticate the request?

I know it's a lot to ask but if anyone is willing to give a basic server example of how to authenticate a vimeo api call in node you would be more help than I think you realize. All I want to do is be able to call https://api.vimeo.com/videos?query=hello&client_id=my_oauth_client_id_here and get the results, nothing else.

Seriously, any help at all is appreciated, I'm completely lost. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try running the examples? Specifically this one: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js/blob/master/example/auth_example.js

Comment: I failed to notice those. Thank you haha. That should suffice.